# php getting values out of an array with same 'id' number

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble getting the value out of an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => id
    [column_name] => id
)
Array
(
    [0] => businessType
    [column_name] => businessType
)
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [column_name] => name
)
Array
(
    [0] => city
    [column_name] => city
)
...
```

I'm getting those values from

```
mysql_query("
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='businessUpgrade' 
")
```

And in my while loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   while($column = mysql_fetch_array($colName)){
     if($row[$i] == 1){
             //here comes the missing part
     }
     $i++;
   }
}
```

I tried diffrent things, but according to print_r, the values I need to get have the same number of id (0). Is there any way, I can get the values out of this array.
I found that I should do it with foreach, but somehow everything I try it fails.

Comment: Why do you have two `while` loops?  What are `$result` and `$colName`?  Do you have two SQL queries?

Comment: The first one, checks values in other table, and when the value in other table is true/1, it should print out the value from the "problematic" table (same count number)

Comment: Every row has a `0` index, so just *always* do `$row[0]`.  No need for a counter.

Comment: What is the other SQL query?  With your 2 loops like this, you are checking *every* row in the first query against *every* row in the second query.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: In first query a grab a lot of 0 an 1 from a table. When the counter gets to the point where the value in the first table equals 1, it should "enter" second table, and get the column_name

Comment: Why not use just one SQL query for that?  Using a `JOIN` perhaps?

Comment: Using two loops like this is not the correct way to do this.  You need to get the second array at the correct position.  Have a look at `mysql_data_seek`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use 2 while loops.
The `$row` array is an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), so you can use...

```
$columns = array();
// {query}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $columns[] = $row['column_name'];
}

var_dump($columns);
```

Your `$columns` array now contains an index of all the columns. It's a zero-index, so these can be pulled individually using:

```
echo $columns[0]; // The first column from the query "id"
echo $columns[2]; // The third column from the query "name"
```

You can also loop this array as needed.

```
foreach ($columns as $id => $column) {
    if ($id == 0) {
        // Do something with the first column:
        echo $column;
    } elseif ($id == 2) {
        // Do something with the third column:
        echo $column;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way, i can only get values from 1,3,6,7... array.
This is why i need the second loop

Comment: @Sebastjan, There are no 1,3,6,7 or any id index fields in your SQL query. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Sebastjan, If you want the 1st, 3rd, 6th and 7th columns, I can edit the answer to provide that solution for you.

Comment: That what I wanted to ask, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$res = mysql_query("
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name='businessUpgrade' 
");

while($r = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
$arr[]=$r;
}
```

NOTE . do not use mysql. Try mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

And with this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  while($column = mysql_fetch_assoc($colName)){
  if(($column['0'] == $row[$i]) && ($row[$i] == 1)){
         //something like this???
  }
}
  $i++;
}
```

Your question is a bit messy XD.....i hope this helps anyway.